# Рекуррентная сортировка пузырьком

Tags: c++, c, сортировка

Попытался рекуррентно переписать сортировку пузырьком. Программа перед отсортированным массивом выводит множество нулей.

```
#include <cstdio>
void rec_bub_sort(int arr[], int size);

int main(void)
{
    #define ARR_SIZE 50    
    int my_arr[ARR_SIZE] = { 5, 15, 6, 12, 8, 14, 6, 4 };    
    rec_bub_sort(my_arr, ARR_SIZE);
    printf("Sorted array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d ", my_arr[i]);
    return 0;
}

void rec_bub_sort(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int n = 1, temp = 0; n < size; n++)
    {
        if (arr[n - 1] > arr[n])
        {
            temp = arr[n];
            arr[n] = arr[n - 1];
            arr[n - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    if (size > 1)
        rec_bub_sort(arr, size - 1);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Забавное условие `(n = 1) < size` - при `size > 1` всегда истинно, так что цикл вечный, с `n==1`. Даже интересно, а что вы хотели тут написать на самом деле?

Comment: @Harry, `size` уменьшается на 1 при каждом вызове функции, поэтому рано или поздно `size` будет равен 1 и рекурсия завершится.

Comment: и ещё рекурсивно и рекуррентно это разные слова :)

Comment: @PavelParshin Наверное, вы посмотрели на уже исправленный код. Там был типичный бесконечный цикл...

Comment: в заголовке "рекуррентно", а по факту рекурсия

Answer (score 3):

Вы объявляете массив с количеством элементов 50 и заполняете его 8 числами. Все остальные элементы будут проинициализированы стандартными значениями - в вашем случае это нули, поэтому после сортировки вы их и видите.
[Подробнее](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) про инициализацию массивов.